# How do I add and remove an event listener using a function with parameters?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, addeventlistener, dom-events

Sorry if this is a common question, but I couldn't find any answers that seemed pertinent through searching.

If I attach an event listener like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { check_pos(box); }, false);
```

it doesn't seem to work to try to remove it later, like this:

```
window.removeEventListener('scroll', function() { check_pos(box); }, false);
```

I assume this is because the `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` methods want a reference to the same function, while I've provided them with anonymous functions, which, while identical in code, are not literally the same.

How can I change my code to get the call to `removeEventListener` to work? The "box" argument refers to the name of an `<iframe>` that I'm tracking on the screen; that is, I want to be able to subscribe to the `scroll` event once for each `<iframe>` that I have (the quantity varies), and once the `check_pos()` function measures a certain position, it will call another function and also remove the event listener to free up system resources.

My hunch is that the solution will involve a closure and/or naming the anonymous function, but I'm not sure exactly what that looks like, and would appreciate a concrete example.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 27):

Have you tried maintaining a reference to the anonymous function (like you suggested)?

So:

```
var listener = function() {
  check_pos(box);
};

window.addEventListener('scroll', listener, false);
...
window.removeEventListener('scroll', listener, false);
```

Mozilla's docs [suggest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, Vivin - correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this would allow me to set up multiple event listeners with different values for "box," which is what I need to do. The argument "box" isn't a global variable. For example, just using literal values, I might call `window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { do_something('string1'); }, false);` and later `window.removeEventListener('scroll', function() { do_something('string1'); }, false);` and later `window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { do_something('string2'); }, false);`, etc.

Comment: There is a way to add multiple event listeners by using closures (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276961/is-there-for-window-onload-in-javascript/2277000#2277000). However I'd suggest using jQuery if you want to do some serious event-handling. It makes it much easier.

Comment: If remove it by using < window.removeEventListener('scroll', listener, false); >  and check again by using < "listener" in window" > so it is still giving me back "true". Any help?

Answer (score 3):

```
var listener;

listener = function(){

if( window.target != anotherEvent.target )
{
    ...CODE where

    window.removeEventListener('click', listener , false);

};

window.addEventListener('click', listener ,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("yourId").removeEventListener("click",yourfunction1);
document.getElementById("yourId").addEventListener("click",yourfunction2);

function yourfunction1(){
//write code here
alert(1);
}

function yourfunction2(){
//write code here
alert(2);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="yourfunction1()" id="yourId">Button</button>
```