# javascript onclick set to false

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = false;
```

I did this to stop getting on click event after the first one and when I want to set it back to normal

```
document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = True;
```

it does not take click events

Comment: This is not how it will work. You want to attach and remove the function. 
If you are not concerned with other mouse events like hover, you can toggle pointer events

Comment: use `removeEventListener()`. or add an `if` function inside your listener, and check if it has been clicked before.

Comment: Thats not how you add and remove a click event. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991382/how-do-i-add-and-remove-an-event-listener-using-a-function-with-parameters)

Comment: Feels like an XY problem here: so you want the first click to do nothing, but all subsequent clicks to work? If that's the case, you can track the number of times the item has clicked on: and use that logic in the handler directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could always disable the button, like this:

`document.getElementById("btn2").disabled = true;`

This sets the disabled attribute to true, therefore stopping the onClick function from being called when the user clicks the button.

Comment: Sorry if this doesn't work, I'm not fully understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable boolean and change using logical not operator (!: see in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT), example:

```js
let toggle = true;
let button = document.querySelector('button');
let result = document.querySelector('span');

button.onclick = () => {
  toggle = !toggle;
  result.textContent = `Your switch to ${toggle}`;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not set onclick event as `True` instead try this way.

```js
const setEvent = (enable) => {
 if(enable){
    document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener('click', onClickEvent);
 }
 else{
    document.getElementById("btn2").removeEventListener('click');
 }
}

function onClickEvent(){
   //Your actual event when clicking the button
}

//Now enable or disable the event as follows
setEvent(true);  //Will attach the event
setEvent(false); //Will remove the event
```

Make sure you call `setEvent(true)` once only, because it can attach multiple events.